# To ignore echo while doing grep

Tags: unix, grep

I am having a file which has content like below

```
+ echo Aus is
```

I am using grep Aus but need to ignore `+ echo`

```
grep Aus input.txt
```

Comment: does the file contain more lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are doing some shell debug output (`set -x`) processing :-)

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(Aus .*\)/\1/p' input.txt
Aus is
```

This removes everything before `Aus` and prints the rest.

Answer (score 0):

So you need only to display the matchin part? If so then use `-o`:

```
grep -o Aus input.txt
```

BTW. On most systems you can see the help for grep using `man grep`.

Comment: sorry i need to display "Aus is"

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o 'Aus.*' input
Aus is
```

This will print Anything which is followed by *"Aus"*.